# error string length compare javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check the size of the string entered in a text box. what am I missing?

```
function test()
{

if((window.document.form.mdp.length)<=6)
alert("Mot de passe faible ");

else if((window.document.form.mdp.length)>6)
alert("Mot de passe fort ");

}
```

Comment: even without() its not working

Comment: What is "mdp" a text field? You need to get the VALUE of the text field and check the length, not the length of the element itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the value of the field. Like this:

```
function test()
{
    var password = window.document.form.mdp.value;

    if(password.length <=6)
        alert("Mot de passe faible ");

    else if(password.length > 6)
        alert("Mot de passe fort ");

}
```

Notes:

If you assigned an id to the text field, you can access it without having to refer to window.

```
var password = mdp.value;
```

This should be enough, yet it's not really explicit and could end up creating more problems than solutions.

Create variables instead of refering directly to the field/value everywhere... It's less typing and makes it easy to update the value everywhere where it's used.